# Assets and S3 - Reduced Redundacy Storage

Tags: assets, s3

is it possible for S3 bucket assets to use reduced redundancy storage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was under impression that it was a bucket setting, but after doing some reading, it seems that this is a per-object setting and should be performed while uploading to a bucket. I'll add this to the list and you can expect to see this in Craft 2.2!